# Why is projection not working using my MapView's spatial reference? (ArcGIS SDK for Android)

Tags: android, arcgis

I have a `MapView` called `mMapView`. I want to add a point graphic to the map. Here is what I did:

```
Point p1 = new Point(66.9969, 6.65428); //I took this coordinate from my GPS device for demonstration
Point p2 = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(
    p1,
    SpatialReference.create(4326),
    mMapView.getSpatialReference());
Graphic graphic = new Graphic(
    p2,
    new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED, 10, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.DIAMOND));
mGraphicsLayer.addGraphic(graphic);//mGraphicsLayer is my GraphicsLayer on my MapView
```

When I ran my program the marker was not there on my `MapView`. But when I replaced `mMapView.getSpatialReference()` with `SpatialReference.create(32637)` the graphic appeared in exactly the right position I wanted. Why this is happening? I checked my `MapView` spatial reference `id` and `latestid` and and it is **102100** and **3857** respectively.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the map doesn't yet have its spatial reference when you call `project`. It's hard to say because you didn't say where in the app your code snippet is. But if you put it in your `Activity`'s `onCreate` method, the map's spatial reference is probably `null` still. Try an `OnStatusChangedListener`, like this:

```
mMapView.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {

    public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
        if (STATUS.INITIALIZED.equals(status)) {
            mGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
            mMapView.addLayer(mGraphicsLayer);

            Point p1 = new Point(66.9969, 6.65428);
            Point p2 = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(
                    p1,
                    SpatialReference.create(4326),
                    mMapView.getSpatialReference());
            Graphic graphic = new Graphic(
                    p2,
                    new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED, 10, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.DIAMOND));
            mGraphicsLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
        }
    }

});
```

Another possibility is that your coordinates are not in latitude and longitude. As written, with lon = 66.9969 and lat = 6.65428, it should be in the ocean near India. If you meant lon = 6.65428 and lat = 66.9969, it would be in the ocean near Norway. If you didn't mean either of those locations, then your coordinates are either incorrect or not in latitude and longitude.